# Table column with zero width

Tags: html, css

Is it possible at all?

I have table that fills its container. (width 100%)
Two of its columns (1st and 3rd) have minimum width, but middle one does not.

When I am narrowing the window, I want 1st and 3rd columns to stay at minimum width, while middle column have to collapse completely (when window is too narrow, just 1st and 3rd columns must be displayed).

Thanks.

There is simplified code of what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first styled page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
.overflow{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.first{
    min-width: 20px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="first"><div class="overflow">oneoneoneone</div></td>
            <td class="second"><div class="overflow">twotwotwotwo</div></td>
            <td class="first"><div class="overflow">threethreethree</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use Javascript to check the width of the container, and if a width goes lesser than a certain value, change the width of second column to zero, or make its visibility hidden.
Though putting div inside Tables isnt considered a good practice, I must say.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be zero width if the td has any data in it.. I may be mistaken.

Comment: @Pratik I am mistaken :)

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript or Media queries to detect the width of the container, and then you could just do some css like `td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2)  {display:none;}`

Comment: @MLeFevre, thats what I meant, thanks for the syntax:)

Comment: @Pratik, (MLeFevre) - by using javascript it really should work (thanks for the idea). But is there any way to do this with just css (for cases, when JS is turned off)? Maybe some kind of way to hide it at least to extent, when letters can not be seen.

Comment: @Adsy - I couldn't find any proof to that. can you, please, share it if you did?

Comment: @Murval I'm pretty sure you can't with just HTML or CSS but I didn't take into account javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with some basic CSS styling & media queries, here's an example

```
<table border=1>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 Col 3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
    table td:nth-child(2), table th:nth-child(2)  {
        display:none;
    }
}
</style>
```

So when the screen is smaller than 500px, the 2nd column will hide.

Fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9rEgQ/2/

Comment: This is the right way to go.  Never use Javascript when CSS can give the solution.

Comment: Not the best solution I was expecting, but it can be done this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS and a media query to hide the middle column when the screen reduced to a specified width.

For example:

```
@media all and (max-width:500px) {
.second {
display: none;
} 
}
```

In this example, the second column would not be displayed when the screen was reduced to a width of less than 500px